# Why/how are some drugs nephrotoxic?

Tags: medications, toxicity, kidney

I want to know the (more or less) exact mechanism by which specific nephrotoxic medications damage the kidneys. For some drugs it seems relatively intuitive that they interfere with the function of the kidneys but I don't know the exact mechanism. I'd like to know especially about how the nephrotoxicity works from NSAIDs, beta-blockers, diuretics, immunesuppressants and antibiotics.

Comment: https://academic.oup.com/jac/advance-article-abstract/doi/10.1093/jac/dkz325/5542610

Comment: "... (more or less) exact ... " is quite contradicting